# Join hint to specify that a left join can return at most 1 row

Tags: sql-server

Let's say you are doing a count query that contains a left join. Let's also say that we know for a fact that the left join will return at most 1 row (for each outer row). From this, we can conclude that the left join cannot affect the count, hence it is unnecessary to perform the left join. In SQL Server, is it possible to express that a left join can result in at most 1 row being returned, thereby allowing the optimiser to skip the left join for a count query? I know you can do it with an outer apply, but I was wondering if you could do with with a plain left join. In my particular case, not performing this left join for the count query saves a lot of time.

Outer Apply example

```
Select count(*)
from table1 a
outer apply ( select top 1 * from table2 b where a.id = b.id) q
```

The optimiser is smart enough to not perform the outer apply. My question is, can you also do this with a plain left join?

Comment: Why do the `LEFT JOIN` at all if you're not using that table anyway?

Comment: The query retrieves the data to be displayed in a user interface grid. I call the query once to get the paginated rows to be displayed, and then I call it again to get the total count of rows (to display in the bottom right of the grid). The data query requires the left join, the count query does not.

Comment: "*The data query requires the left join, the count query does not.*" - Right, and the count query is the one you're trying to add a hint to. But why not just not do the `LEFT JOIN` in that instance?

Comment: The count query and the data query call the same inline table valued function (which contains the meat of the query, including the left join). The "framework" we are using calls this function with either a count for the count query, or  a select <colum names> for the data query. I want the count query to skip the left join, and the data query to not. Of course I could do this with two different table value functions, but I'd rather not. Hence I want to know how I can coax sql server into skipping the left join when the query is being called in the content of a count.  Outer apply does this.

Comment: "*Of course I could do this with two different table value functions, but I'd rather not.*" - No offense, but it's rather silly to build something the wrong way with hopes it works out the right way as opposed to just building it the right way. ‍♂️ You can't rely on the optimizer to always generate the same plan anyway, so even if you find a way, it's not guaranteed to always be the execution plan you get. Additionally, if you're already scanning the whole table to get the count, you're doing the bulk of the work and might as well just return all the rows anyway, it's not much different.

Comment: So duplicating code is the right way to do things? Isn't it better to have 1 function that contains the business logic for a thing?

Comment: "*So duplicating code is the right way to do things?*" - Yes, in the database layer, for the tradeoff of maximizing performance, it's commonly accepted that duplicating code is a correct design pattern.

Comment: Does `table2` have a unique constraint on `id`?

Comment: @MartinSmith The example in my question is a simplified. The real query is left joinign on a table valued function that itself joins on several tables. But, I know for a fact that the table valued function should and can only return 1 row for each outer row. So it seems like what I want to do is not possible. I think it's cool that it works for outer apply, i think sql server should add a feature that lets your specify if 1 row should be returned for a join, as it will improve optimisation. I have use top 1 in cross and outer apply on many occasion to improve performance.

Comment: @jd Unfortunately our "framework" makes it difficult to have a separate function for obtaining the count and the data. That's why I wanted to avoid it.

Comment: @user23278799 Heads up, you need to type the periods in my name for me to get notified. I just coincidentally looked back and saw you replied. Did you guys write the function?

Comment: @J.D. Nope, just going with the outer apply, as the framework we are using makes it difficult to have 2 different functions.

Comment: @user23278799 "*framework we are using makes it difficult to have 2 different functions*" - Not sure what that actually means without seeing it. But clearly you're able to run two different queries if you're trying to run one as a `SELECT COUNT(*)` and another as `SELECT SomeColumns`. If that's so, then your other query could theoretically recreate what the function is doing under the hood. Alternatively, it would probably be the better solution to tally the count from the regular query in application code or use a grid that does that for you (which is surprising isn't the case already).

Comment: In the framework we are using, breeze.js, you configure a table (or table valued function) to query again. The framework then issues a "data" and "count" query against this table.  You can't perform the count manually,  or tell the framework that the count query should be run against another table.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, a left join will always return all matches from the joined table/view.

Less directly, you could use a CTE with the `row_number` window function and left join to that with a filter on rownumber=1. This may be more efficient than your `outer apply` depending on other parts of the query but you'll need to look at plans produced an IO stats of each option with realistic data to be sure either way.

Comment: The optimiser isn't smart enough to know that rownumber=1 results in at most 1 joined row per outer row.

Comment: @user23278799 - no, but such a CTE based query may result in seeking based on other filters (maybe still followed by a partial scan) or a scan down a relevant index, in each case due to predicate push-down into the CTE, where `OUTER APPLY` could result in the correlated query being run once per matching row. In some cases this might be far more efficient. Of course the opposite may be better in some queries too, hence I pointed out the need to compare plans and IO stats with real data.